# How can I check the last backup date on iCloud?

Tags: icloud

My daughter's iPad was completely destroyed. I pay for an iCloud plan using Family Sharing, and her iPad was setup to backup to iCloud.

How can I check the last backup date on iCloud, considering that the iPad was destroyed?

Comment: If this is under your iCloud account, you should see it listed under iCloud > Account Storage > Manage.. > Backups.

Answer (score 0):

If you sign in to iCloud.com with the AppleID used to set up the Family Plan, then click on Drive, you'll get a list of Recents, ordered by Previous 7 Days, Previous 30 Days, then the preceding months.

I don't have access to an iCloud Family Plan, but I imagine the process should be fairly similar.